# I am trying to make a select tag dynamically in react

Tags: reactjs

```
let select_options = []
export const serverCall = async (value) => {
  try {
    const response = await axois.post('test/', value)
      .catch(error => {
          some error code ..

        }
      })
      if (response && response.data) {
      select_options = response.data
    }
  } catch (error) {
    
  } finally {
    
  }
}

export async function makeSelectTag(type_code,group_code) {
  await serverCall({'type_code':type_code,'group_code':group_code})
  console.log(select_options) //It clearly contains the value I want.
  return (<Select style={{ width: 150 }}  >
  {options.map((item) => (
    <Option key={item.code_id}>{item.code_name}</Option>
     ))}                
  </Select>

);
}
export default(commonCodeCall, makeSelectTag)
```

The code above is called from the code below.

```
import makeSelectTag from '../myPath'
....
return (
      <div>
        <Form.Item>
          {makeSelectTag('type_code','group_code')}
        </Form.Item>
       ...
```

Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

How can I solve the problem and make it work?

Comment: makeSelectTag returns a Promise, which isn’t a valid React element. async functions return Promises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you shouldn't really make a `makeSelectTag` function. Instead create a `SelectTag` component that takes data and load it into some state on mount stage:

```
export function SelectTag({ type_code, group_code }) {
  const [options, setOptions] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const getOptions = async () => {
      const selectedOptions = await serverCall({ type_code, group_code })
      setOptions(selectedOptions)
    }

    getOptions()
  }, [])

  return (
    <Select style={{ width: 150 }}>
      {options.map((item) => (
        <Option key={item.code_id}>{item.code_name}</Option>
      ))}
    </Select>
  )
}
```

and at your component call it as:

```
    <Form.Item>
      <SelectTag type_code='foo' group_code='bar' />
    </Form.Item>
```

Comment: wow.. only admiration comes out. It works exactly as I wanted it to. I took so long on this problem.. I really respect it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

```
{options.map((item) => (
    <Option key={item.code_id}>{item.code_name}</Option>
     ))}                
  </Select>
)}
```

- please rewrite options into select_options.
- I hope it will work successfully.
  Nice day:)